# Displaying entire vector shows only zeros but displaying a any single element shows a correct nonzero number

Tags: matlab, vector, plot

I have a vector defined like this `x=(1:1000)` and another vector `y` of the same size with a lot of different numbers like those:

```
-0.0019
-0.0018
-0.0018
-0.0019
-0.0019
-0.0020
```

I have copied the values of `y` to `x` with a `while` statement and when I put in the console `x(1)` the result is `-0.0019`, just like `y(1)` and so on with the rest of the indexes but when I put in the console `x` it shows a list like this:

```
-0.0000
-0.0000
-0.0000
-0.0000
```

In the workspace, the value of both vectors is `<1000x1 double>` and when I plot the 2 vectors the graph of `y` is alright but the graph of `x` is a line of zeros

This is my code:

```
%Grabar audio en un archivo
Fs = 200000;
y = wavrecord(1*Fs, Fs, 1); %10 segundos
wavwrite(y,Fs,'cancion.wav'); 


%Leer el archivo y graficar las ondas
[wave,fs] = wavread('cancion.wav');  
t = 0:1/fs:(length(wave)-1)/fs;

sound(wave,fs)
plot(t,wave)

fs2 = 1000;
j=1;
i=1;
xa=(1:fs2);
while j<fs2
    xa(j) = wave(i);
    i=i+Fs/fs2;
    j=j+1;
end

intervalo = 0:1/fs2:1-(1/fs2);
xa=xa';
figure(2)
plot(intervalo,xa);

%display(length(wave))
```

Anyone can tell me what is happening?

Comment: Can you include the code with the `while`?

Comment: Post your code, it will be easier for us to debug, but very nice description of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line 17, use: `xa=zeros(1,fs2);`

Comment: i alredy tried that, shows this error.... Error using zeros
Maximum variable size allowed by the program is exceeded.

Error in voz (line 17)
xa=zeros(1:fs2);

Comment: There is a comma in between.